# Handling CORs inside of node behind nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

At the moment I'm handling CORs within node.js which seems to be working pretty well; I can setup multiple domains and hit my node.js code just fine.

The trouble is once I put node.js inside of forever and run a proxy from nginx to my application it no longer handles any CORs requests. In fact they never even make it to the server and I'm having trouble figuring out why. Below is my nginx configuration; any suggestions? If it isn't obvious I'm trying to hit the services.org from the webapp.org. In this environment they're on the same box but in other environments and when consumed by third parties we need CORs working.

```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  webapp.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/Site/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  services.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the nginx.conf

Comment: I tried this under Ryan's answer but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an upstream server like this:

```
upstream my_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name webapp.org;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_app.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      root /var/www/my_app/public;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_redirect off;
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
        break;
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I updated my configuration to use upstream and 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but no good. In fact I exactly copied and pasted your entire configuration, tweaked the obvious things like server_name but still no luck.

Comment: Very strange... I am using this config in my setup and don't have any issues with CORS. When you start node with forever can you still hit node at port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable CORS for the service via:

`app.enableCors()` in your `bootstrap()` function in main.ts